# Read unstructured CSV

Tags: python, csv

I want to parse a given csv file, that looks like

```
"header_1" ; "header_2"; "header_3"
"a" ; "b" ; "c"
"1" ; "2" ; "3"

Some footer text; maybe more.
```

Only well and correct structured fields shall be parsed. How can I enforce that?

The following code does the job:

```
with open(path) as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=";", strict=False)
    result = []
    for row in reader:
        if row == []:
            break
        result += [row]
```

Is there a smarter, pythonic solution without checking the line if it is empty or not? In general, I would prefer [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).

Comment: you mean only rows containing 3 fields shall be parsed right? what bothers you really with your solution? listcomps are out of the question because of the `break` statement.

Comment: In my opinion this does not look like very pythonic. So I am curious how a better solution could look like.

Comment: DictReader does the job! Tat basically `read into a dict whose keys are given by the optional fieldnames parameter` and fieldnames is not given, `the values in the first row of the csvfile will be used as the fieldnames`. The empty lines are thus omitted!

Comment: The code in your question will not read the csv file shown in your question. `_csv.Error: ';' expected after '"'` Please fix the problem.

Comment: I suggest you be more explicit about what constitutes a 'correct' line (e.g. every line that contains `n` delimiters, or every line before the first blank line if any). Then reflect that in your code by first filtering those lines (e.g. using a generator expression) and parsing them only after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `break` you can use the fact that empty lists evaluate to `false` and use a while loop instead:

```
while row in reader:
    result.append(row)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can break out of your condition using `itertools.takewhile`, which creates a nice one-liner:

```
import itertools

result = list(itertools.takewhile(bool,reader))
```

when the row is empty, converting to `bool` yields `False` and `takewhile` stops iterating on your reader.

The conversion to `list` is just for display purposes. You don't have to convert if you just want to iterate on the rows (which avoids the creation of a list)

BTW: your input file has some extra spaces which make the reader fail. After fixing them I get with the above line:

```
[['header_1', 'header_2', 'header_3'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', '3']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using your code snippet

```
import csv
with open("a.csv") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=";", strict=False)
    result = []
    #First get everything in list
    for row in reader:
        result.append(row)
#Filter list only for row with 3 elements.Blank line got ignored also
final = [r for r in result if len(r)==3]
print final
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\dinesh\Desktop>python demo.py
[['header_1 ', ' "header_2"', ' "header_3"'], ['a ', ' "b" ', ' "c"'], ['1 ', '"2" ', ' "3"']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generator, although its not exactly shorter:

```python
def get_lines(path):
    for line in csv.reader(open(path), delimiter=";"):
        if line:
            yield line
        else:
            break

f = [i for i in get_lines("blah.csv")]
print f
```

Comment: But in my opinion nicer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, under either Python 2 or 3, I get a `csv.Error` exception:

```
  File "so1.py", line 7, in <module>
    for row in reader:
_csv.Error: ';' expected after '"'
```

Spaces aren't allowed around field delimiters in the CSV "standard". When I set `strict` to `False`, however, I get three data rows and one empty row, then the output stops because the `break` statement terminates execution of the loop. Replacing `break` (terminate loop) with `continue` (end this iteration) gives a fourth row: `['Some footer text', ' maybe more.']`.

So it would appear that your test needs to be a little more specific if you want to handle data errors - maybe test for exactly three values, and ignore any line that has a different number?